# absolutely convergent & conditionally convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, absolute-convergence

Prove that

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{{{1}}}{{{m}}}\right)\frac{{{\sin(nx)}}}{{{n}}} $$

for $x = {k\pi}$ ,   $k\in \mathbb{Z} $ is absolutely convergent.

&

for $x \not= {k\pi}$ ,   $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ is conditionally convergent.

Comment: Use the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula to prove that $\sum_{m=1}^n 1/m = \ln n + \gamma + O(1/n)$. After that, split the series into three parts and use Dirichlet's test to prove convergence of two of them. To prove that the sum doesn't converge absolutely when $x \ne k\pi$, find a lower bound (depending on $x$) for $|\sin nx| + |\sin (n+1)x|$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$ we are just summing zeroes, so there is little to prove.
If $x\not\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$, from:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(nx)=\frac{\sin\frac{Nx}{2}\sin\frac{(N+1)x}{2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}\in\left[-\frac{1}{2}\tan\frac{x}{4},\frac{1}{2}\cot\frac{x}{4}\right]$$
and the fact that $\frac{H_n}{n}$ is eventually decreasing and converging to zero, we get that the original series is conditionally convergent by [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) or just summation by parts. In such a case, however, the series is not absolutely convergent since, given that $\pi a$ is the closest element of $\pi\mathbb{Z}$ to $x$ and $d=\left|a -\frac{x}{\pi}\right|\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, the asymptotic density of the integers $m$ such that $|\sin(mx)|\geq\frac{1}{2}$ can be lower-bounded in terms of $d$.

For $x\not\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$, we have:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n}\sin(nx)=\text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{2}\log^2(1-e^{ix})+\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{ix})\right).$$

<sup>$H_n$ stands for the $n$-th harmonic number: $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$.</sup>